# How to sort JavaScript object by its values?

Tags: javascript, sorting, javascript-objects

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var foo = {
    284366: 3, 
    285286: 1, 
    285614: 2
}
```

How can I turn it into:

```
var foo = {
    285286: 1, 
    285614: 2,
    284366: 3
}
```

Comment: Javascript objects don't guarantee any order. The order is JS engine implementation-specific and may change during the program execution flow.

Comment: You can't.  Objects in JavaScript aren't in a set order.  If you want a guaranteed order, use an array.

Comment: You cannot order the members of a JavaScript object. Why do you think you need this? For all other cases check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_sort

Comment: @André w3schools is a terrible resource.

Comment: What about `oof = [, 285286, 285614, 284366]`?

Comment: @Jan do you think so? I like these little nice tutorials and they are sometimes a quite good starting point ... :)

Comment: @André http://w3fools.com

Comment: @André w3schools contain so much misinformation and bad advices they are not worth linking even if they're (rarely) right